# remove unwanted groups of characters from string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Given: `1999 some text here 1.3i [more]`
Needed: `some text here`

The following regex - `replace(/[\d{4} |\d\.*$]/,'')` - failed, it just removed the first digit. Any idea why and how to fix it?

```js
var s = "1999 some text here 1.3i [more]"
console.log(s.replace(/[\d{4} |\d\.*$]/,''))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you have removes the first digit only because it matches just 1 char - either a digit, `{`, `4`, `}`, space, `|`, `.`, `*` or `$` (as `[...]` formed a *character class*), just once (there is no global modifier).

You may use

```
/^\d{4}\s+|\s*\d\..*$/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xfiM2P/3)

Basically, remove the `[` and `]` that form a character class, add `g` modifier to perform multiple replacements, and add `.*` (any char matching pattern) at the end.

**Details**:

First alternative: 
 - `^` - start of string
 - `\d{4}` - 4 digits
 - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces

Second alternative: 
 - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
 - `\d` - a digit
 - `\.` - a dot
 - `.*` - any 0+ chars up to...
 - `$` - the end of the string

```js
var rx = /^\d{4}\s+|\s*\d\..*$/g;
var str = "1999 some text here 1.3i [more]";
console.log(str.replace(rx, ''));
```